# How to run a spark file with spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark

I wrote a HelloWorld spark application. The file looks like this:

```
object HelloWorld{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    println("HelloWorld")
  }
}
```

but it's just a file. I want to run it from the bash terminal and not from the spark-shell. I would like to make a scheduled task with crontab. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command to run spark application.

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class>
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

Simple example :

```
spark-submit --class WordCount MyJarFile.jar fileURL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined an object inside a scala file e.g. `file.scala` like

```
//file.scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
object App{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val spark = (
            SparkSession
            .builder
            .getOrCreate()
        )
        import spark.implicits._

        println("Hello world")
    }
}
```

you can run it inside spark-shell with:

1. first run the spark shell with

```
spark-shell
```

2. then in the console write:

```
scala> :load file.scala
scala> App.main(Array())
```

Alternatively you can run it as a script:

```
//build.sbt
name := "app"
version :="0.0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
)
```

and compile it with

```
sbt clean package
```

then run the script with

```
spark-submit --class App target/scala-2.11/app_2.11-0.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The program you have written is pure scala object. You can easily run it from bash as:

```
scalac program.scala
scala HelloWorld
```

Or if you have a spark program written then you can use below given command to run it from bash but remember you need to call driver class for it:

```
spark-shell -i program.scala
```